# How to change x-bind:value before displaying - Alpine JS

Tags: javascript, html, alpine.js

```
<div x-data="{ date : false }">
      <input type="date" name="dateOne" id="dateOne" x-model="date">
      <input type="date" name="dateTwo" id="dateTwo" x-bind:value="date">
</div>
```

Now, how do I change the #dateTwo, so once the #dateOne changes I display #dateTwo with a day ahead, I already know to create a day and add one more in JavaScript. But my trouble lies in the logic of how to glue it with Alpine JS.

The scenario: there is an event that has a starting and a ending date, but I want to force the use to pick at least a day ahead. So my idea is this, as soon as the user chooses a day on the first input the x-bind on the second input will add and display a day ahead

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hey Lucas, welcome to Stackoverflow!
Your question isn't clear enough! What needs to happen when? What's the use case?

Comment: The scenario: there is an event that has a starting and a ending date, but I want to force the use to pick at least a day ahead. So my idea is this, as soon as the user chooses a day on the first input the x-bind on the second input will add and display a day ahead

Comment: @KarimTarek, and also edited the question. I hope the logic is a bit clean now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The model/data is missing a couple of values, my approach is a bit different than yours, I didn't think we need `x-model` for the first date, it made more sense to be used in the second date.
Below is a quick and dirty solution to your use case:

```
<div x-data="{ 
  dateStart: null,
  dateEnd: null,
  initEndDate: function(dateStartInputValue) {
    const selectedDate = new Date(dateStartInputValue); 
    const dateEndInitValue = selectedDate.setDate(selectedDate.getDate() + 1);
    this.dateEnd = new Date(dateEndInitValue).toISOString().split('T')[0];
  }
}">
  <label for="start">
    Start date:
    <input 
      name="dateStart" 
      type="date" 
      @change="dateStart = event.target.value; initEndDate(event.target.value)" 
    />
  </label>
  <label for="dateEnd" x-show="dateStart">
    – End date:
    <input 
      name="dateStart" 
      type="date" 
      x-model="dateEnd"
      @change="dateEnd = event.target.value;" 
    />
  </label>
</div>
```

Here is the code in a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/thirsty-hodgkin-u8b78).

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for the answer. There is not dirty code, there is only code that works for specific circumstance, and in my point of view, yours is a killer.

Comment: Thanks Lucas! One case you need to account for is when the user changes the start date after the initial date selection because that will trigger the change of the end date, this isn't accounted for in the code above. It would be greatly appreciated if you find value in my answer to upvoted, thanks!